# Why do these white seams appear on my meshes in AFrame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I import a GLB scene (with baked textures) in AFrame using THREEjs but for some reason these white lines appear on my objects (check example photo bellow).

The walls are actually grouped meshes so I can somewhat understand why the lines appear, but I cant understand why it happens on the objects too. When I upload the same scene on the THREE.js/editor the white seams don't appear so I assume its a setting that AFrame sets automatiacally?

Each object is a single material with a single "map" texture. Does anyone know why it happens and how to avoid it? Thank you in advance!

[An example photo of the white seams. They appear in the perimeter of each unwrapped UV part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci3GC.png)

Comment: any chance you upload the model on github or host it somewhere? I'd like to help but I need to reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has an issue with the alpha buffer. Once you disable its usage in the renderer, the mentioned white lines dissapear

```
<a-scene renderer="alpha: false"
```

Check it out [here](https://stack-66983637.glitch.me/)

Comment: Ah that worked, I think I get it now! Thank you so much kind sir!